# How to sort array into seperate arrays based on unknown keys?

Tags: php, sql

I have an array like this, how can I split it into several other arrays, based on the category ID?

i.e. have category 1 -> forum 1, forum 4. category 2 -> forum 3, forum 7

I've looked at array_chunk, but there could be any number of categories or forums

```
Array
(
    [category_id] => 1
    [category_name] => Main
    [forum_id] => 1
    [forum_name] => General forum
)
Array
(
    [category_id] => 1
    [category_name] => Main
    [forum_id] => 2
    [forum_name] => Test forum
)
Array
(
    [category_id] => 2
    [category_name] => Test
    [forum_id] => 3
    [forum_name] => Another test
)
```

I'm using this SQL query (incase it can be done with SQL only before modifying it with PHP)

```
$forums_query = mysqli_query($sql_connect, 'SELECT `categories`.`category_id`, `categories`.`category_name`,
                                            `forums`.`forum_id`, `forums`.`forum_name`, `forums`.`category_id`
                                            FROM `categories`
                                                LEFT JOIN `forums`
                                                    ON `categories`.`category_id` = `forums`.`category_id`
                                            ORDER BY `categories`.`category_position`, `forums`.`forum_position` ASC');
```

Edit: by the way, I can think of one way to do it, which is loop through it, and for every cat ID (as X), check if an array exists called catX and if not create it

However, this will run every time someone visits the page, so I want it to be as quick and light on resources as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get this right, take a look at this demo:

```
<?php
$forums[] = array('category_id' => 1, 'category_name' => 'Main', 'forum_id' => 1, 'forum_name' => 'General forum');
$forums[] = array('category_id' => 1, 'category_name' => 'Main', 'forum_id' => 2, 'forum_name' => 'General 2');
$forums[] = array('category_id' => 1, 'category_name' => 'Main', 'forum_id' => 3, 'forum_name' => 'General 3');
$forums[] = array('category_id' => 1, 'category_name' => 'Main', 'forum_id' => 4, 'forum_name' => 'General 4');
$forums[] = array('category_id' => 2, 'category_name' => 'Main2', 'forum_id' => 1, 'forum_name' => 'General forum');
$forums[] = array('category_id' => 2, 'category_name' => 'Main2', 'forum_id' => 2, 'forum_name' => 'General 2');
$forums[] = array('category_id' => 3, 'category_name' => 'Main3', 'forum_id' => 3, 'forum_name' => 'General 3');
$forums[] = array('category_id' => 4, 'category_name' => 'Main3', 'forum_id' => 4, 'forum_name' => 'General 4');


$forums_organized = array();
foreach($forums as $forum){
    $forums_organized[$forum['category_id']][]  = array('forum_name' => $forum['forum_name'], 'forum_id' => $forum['forum_id']);
}
print_r($forums_organized);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [forum_name] => General forum
                    [forum_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [forum_name] => General 2
                    [forum_id] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [forum_name] => General 3
                    [forum_id] => 3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [forum_name] => General 4
                    [forum_id] => 4
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [forum_name] => General forum
                    [forum_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [forum_name] => General 2
                    [forum_id] => 2
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [forum_name] => General 3
                    [forum_id] => 3
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [forum_name] => General 4
                    [forum_id] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't it INNER JOIN in your case ?!

```
$old_array = array();
$new_array = array();

foreach($old_array AS $tab) {
    if(!array_key_exists($tab['category_name'], $new_array)) {
        $tmp = array($tab['forum_name']);
        $tmp = array($tab['category_name']=>$tmp);
        $new_array = array_merge($new_array, $tmp);
    }
    else {
        array_push($new_array[$tab['category_name']], $tab['forum_name']);
    }
}
```